# Help with sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a recent self assessment we had to evalute the next integer in a sequence (you know the drill).

The given numbers were:

4

8

24

192

And the solution is:

1259712

I have no idea how this is the result. It would be really appreciate if someone could tell me the pattern of this sequence!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The successive differences are 4, 16, and 160: the ratios are 4 and then  10 - well, one could multiply by $10+6=16$ to make the next difference 2560. **So $192+2560=2752$ is a correct answer.**

The successive ratios are 2, 3, and 8. Nothing much to see there, as far as I can see.

The successive differences of the successive differences 4, 16 and 160 are 12 and $144=12^2$, so the next successive differences of successive differences would be $12^3=1728$, so the next successive difference is $160+1728=1888$. **So $192+1888=2080$ is a correct answer.**

The first successive ratio is 2. The second successive ratio is 3. The next is $2^3=8$. Making the next ratio $3^8=6561$. **So $192\times 6561=1259712$ is a correct answer.**

A question with three equally correct answers is a question set by morons whom you should not be paying to write nonsense. Tell them so.

Comment: So many sequence/pattern problems online nowadays have multiple correct solutions, depending on how one looks at it. I can't help but shake my head at them.

Comment: A question with more than one correct answer still can be meaningful, in case any correct answer counts as such. Done right, it becomes a chance to see that there can be more than one proper reasoning and to show some unorthodox thinking. Done wrong, it becomes an attempt to read author thoughts.